# Knockout: subscription to ObservableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am not sure what i'm missing in the following example:
 http://jsfiddle.net/2NMJX/438/ 
But shouldn't the function under subscribe get triggered every time a checkbox is checked and added to the observableArray "selected"  ?

Thank you for the help

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:seats" >
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="text:No"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:$parent.selected(), checkedValue:No" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

var viewModel = {
    seats:ko.observableArray( [
    { "No": "1" }, { "No": "2" },
    { "No": "3" }, { "No": "4"},
   { "No": "5" }, { "No": "6"},
    { "No": "7" }, { "No": "8"},
  { "No": "9" },
    ]),
    selected: ko.observableArray()
};

viewModel.selected.subscribe(
            function(newvalue){
            alert(newvalue);
        }
    );

 ko.applyBindings( viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo I believe.  Just take the `()` off of `checked:$parent.selected` as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:$parent.selected, checkedValue:No" />
```

Might read this to explain some of the behavior:

[KnockOut Checked Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)

> Special consideration is given if your parameter resolves to an array. In this case, KO will set the element to be checked if the value matches an item in the array, and unchecked if it is not contained in the array.
>
> When the user checks or unchecks the checkbox, KO will add or remove the value from the array accordingly.

Comment: I've been looking into this for 2 hours !! no idea how i missed it!!  thank you